# Rails 3 + sendmail on snow leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, sendmail

This is my development.rb file configs for action mailer

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

Everything works on ubuntu but on snow leopard it does nothing .
This is the WEBrick output from the Terminal

```
Sent mail to razha_lesce@yahoo.com (840ms)
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 21:36:00 +0200
from: Notificari eCatalog notificari@ecatalog.com
To: razha_lesce@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <4f4695208bf88_a098103d9102475@Lesce-Andreis-MacBook.local.mail>
Subject: Notificare Ecatalog
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Completed 200 OK in 3448ms (Views: 122.1ms | ActiveRecord: 164.8ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you expecting to happen here? Unless your Mac postfix client is configured with a relayhost to connect to the Internet at large and perform deliveries, mail that you deliver through sendmail locally won't be delivered anywhere at all. As you noticed, you can see the mail in WEBrick's output to verify its content, but unless you take further steps it won't be delivered.

Comment: Your Ubuntu configuration has a working postfix configuration that has a connection to the Internet at large, whereas your Mac does not. If you want to configure your Mac to actually send mail, [check out this blog post](http://blog.subtlecoolness.com/2009/06/enabling-postfix-sendmail-on-mac-os-x.html) that has instructions on how to do that.